# Can't add node at index is list is empty in a doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have created a doubly-linked list that I fill with nodes in Java. I am trying to make a method that adds a node at a certain index. The problem is that I get `NullPointerException` if I try to add a node and there are no other nodes. So I would write `list.add(0, 0);` for example and I would get `NullPointerException` (the first number is index and second is value). However, if I first use my method that just puts in a node and then tries `list.add(0, 0);` or `list.add(1, 0);` it works. I believe the problem lies in how to iterate through the nodes. The code currently looks like this:

```
void add(int index, T t)
    {
        ListNode<T> node = header;
        ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(t);

        if(index < 0 || index > size)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index not allowed");
        }
        int counter = 0;
        while(node.next != null && counter < index)
        {
            node = node.next;
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            header = newNode;
            newNode.next = node;
        }
        else
        {
            node = node.previous;
            ListNode<T> temp = node.next;
            node.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = temp;
        }
        newNode.previous = node;
        newNode.next.previous = newNode;
        size++;
    }
```

And I believe that this is where the problem is:

```
while(node.next != null && counter < index)
```

Do you have an idea on how to do it instead? I can't think of another way.

Comment: Try `while(node != null && node.next != null && counter < index)` 

so it will handle that you will not use null reference for .next condition.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks!